# How to make EditText scrollable after 4 or 5 lines in android?

Tags: android

My EditText is set to wrap content and as i add text it keeps on expanding so at start it looks like the image below:

[image]

Now what i want is that after 4 or 5 lines i want my edit text to scrollable and stop expanding.

[image]

Here is the xml:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#F4F3F6"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/chatInputEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPersonName"
            android:maxLines="10"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/chatImageInput"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.49" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chatImageInput"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_image" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change value of attribute `android:maxLines` to 5 and take a look to the documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:maxLines